# R: mapply with vector argument

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mapply

I have a function of this form:

```
foo<-function(x,y){
  if(length(y)==1){
    return(x*y)
  }
  else{
    return(x-y[1]*y[2])
  }
}
```

and for the *y* argument I pass either a number or a vector of numbers:

```
> #test function:
> foo(1,2)
[1] 2
> foo(1,c(1,2))
[1] -1
```

Now I wish to use mapply to this function, but I run into problems when I wish to pass a vector for the *y* argument:

```
df<-data.frame(
  "a"<-floor(runif(6, 1,10)),
  "b"<-floor(runif(6, 18,80)),
  "c"<-floor(runif(6, 1,80)),
  "d"<-floor(runif(6, 100,800)),
  "e"<-floor(runif(6, 1000,4000)),
  "f"<-floor(runif(6, 1,10)),
  "g"<-floor(runif(6, 5,80))
)
names(df)=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
```

The following works fine:

```
> mapply(FUN=foo,df["a"],df["b"])
```

,but I run into trouble when I try to do the following:

```
> mapply(FUN=foo,df["a"],cbind(df["b"],df["c"]))
```

I'm very grateful for tips on how to better use an argument that have verying length, or how to pass the argument to mapply!

Comment: Why do you want to use `mapply`? Is there something wrong with using `foo(df["a"],cbind(df["b"],df["c"]))`?

Comment: DUDE, I had no idea I could do that!! I thought one had to use the apply functions when mixing functions and vectors! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Ahhh, the wonders of R. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible fixes here.  Fundamentally, you need to turn 2nd input into `mapply` into a list with two elements in each list.  One way to achieve that is to do something like:

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(t(df[c('b', 'c')]))
result <- mapply(FUN=foo,df["a"], tmp)
```

since a data frame is a list.  This is going to run the function on all combinations of `df["a"]` and `tmp`.  The elements you want will be along the diagonal (1st element of `df['a']` with the first element of tmp, so the final answer is

```
diag(result)
```

BTW, when you are inside a function such as `data.frame`, use `=` for assignment instead of `<-`.  You also do not need the quotes around the letters (they are being ignored).  so you're call to `data.frame` should look like

```
df<-data.frame(
  a = floor(runif(6, 1,10)),
  b = floor(runif(6, 18,80)),
  c = floor(runif(6, 1,80)),
  d = floor(runif(6, 100,800)),
  e = floor(runif(6, 1000,4000)),
  f = floor(runif(6, 1,10)),
  g = floor(runif(6, 5,80))
)
```

Which allows you to avoid having to name the data frame after you define it.

**Update without diagonal call**

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) ==2 ) x[1] * x[2]
  else x[1] - x[2]*x[3]
}

apply(df[,c("a","b", "c")], 1, f1)
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for this! :)

Comment: could you elaborate on why we have to use the transpose function?

Comment: A data frame is a special form of list, where each column is an element in the list. The transpose function is going to switch which things are the columns and which are the rows so that when we call as.data.frame, we have what was originally a row as a single element in the list being passsed to mapply.

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to understand how mapply goes through each element. Would there be a way to do this without ending up with having to take the diagonal? I'm suspecting I have misunderstood how mapply works..

Comment: Check out the update - the ``apply`` function goes through the data frame row by row, but you need to feed the entire vector in at once, you can't split it into x and y.